# How to make gulp tasks cross platform. Especially gulp-shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, npm, gulp

I am trying to run some gulp tasks that contain some shell commands. It works perfectly in linux but when I switched to Windows, all the env variables are not accessible through de $var syntax (equivalent to %var% in windows). Do I need to create a specific gulpfile for windows platform or there's any other cleaner way ??

Comment: Linux is unix-based and because of that it has a very powerfull shell. Windows needs some replacements for this, so you'll propably need to write another `gulpfile` for Windows. Also, make sure that Windows installation has all the required addons installed. Clean installation is pretty much useless for today's webdev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by using the cross-env npm package !! Simply run :

```
npm i cross-env --save-dev
```

and then, add the cross-env before setting your environment vars, for example

```
cross-env mode=debug
```

And here's a link for the full documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env